# Sliding scale for secondary stats

Tags: mathematics

So, I’m designing a game where Crit Chance is based on a Prowess Stat but want it to have a sliding scale with diminishing returns and for some reason the math is escaping me. The max value for Crit Chance would be 40%. The min value of Prowess would be 1 but there is no ceiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt basically any function with a horizontal asymptote. Here are a few options:

```
// hyperbolic
critChance = maxChance * (1 - 1/(rate * prowess + 1))

// arc tangent
critChance = maxChance * atan(rate * prowess) * 2/PI

// exponential
critChance = maxChance * (1 - exp(-rate * prowess))
```

These behave similarly, and all reach toward a max of `maxChance` as `prowess` increases toward infinity - they just differ in how steeply they rise initially, and how gradually they brake as they approach that cap.

`rate` in all three is a parameter you can use to control the steepness of the early part of the curve / how quickly it starts to plateau. In this chart, I've plotted the three versions with `rate` tuned so they all pass through the point (15, 25%) to get an apples-to-apples look at how they compare:

[image: Graph comparing the three functions]

If you want to tune the `rate` so the curve passes through a given `(prowess, critChance)` pair, the formulas for that are:

```
// hyperbolic
rate = (1/(1 - critChance/maxChance) - 1) / prowess

// arc tangent
rate = tan(critChance * PI / (2 * maxChance)) / prowess

// exponential
rate = ln(1 - critChance/maxChance) / prowess
```

[I've shared a version of these formulas as a Google Sheets workbook you can play with here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D_JAftzmGpzs5qM2UXRlgjANlHI6QJfl3x-KROXUJog/edit?usp=sharing) - see the "Diminishing Returns" tab. You can set the Min Output to zero if you want zero stat to map to zero chance, as shown above.

[image: Graph comparing the three functions]